# Jquery fade effect while scrolling and change the src

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change my logo while scrolling down, the idea is that they switch between 2 images. first I tried this solution:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

        $('#logo').attr('src','/logo.png');
    } else {
        $('#logo').attr('src','/logo2.png');
    }
});
```

this works, but the bridge between the two images is to big so I tought maybe it is nice to fadeOut and fadeIn the images. then I came with this idea:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

        $("#logo").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('#logo').attr('src','/logo.png');
        }).fadeIn(1000);


    } else {

        $("#logo").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('#logo').attr('src','/logo2.png');
        }).fadeIn(1000);
    };

});
```

This works for 50%, when I scroll down the image fadeOut, but the new one come in like BAM, no fade add all, and when I'm scrolling back up, the first image wil not shown again...

someone who can help me with this please????

mvg,

Comment: I think you need to use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) i.e. `$("#logo").stop(true, true).fadeOut(...`

Comment: the images still not fadeIn and fadeOut :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this short code,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var win=this;
    $("#logo").stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        this.src = $(win).scrollTop() > 200 ? '/logo.png' : '/logo2.png';
    }).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Updated with snippet,

```js
var logo1='http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Images.jpg',
logo2='http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Images-2.jpg';
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#logo").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).attr('src',$(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? logo2 : logo1).fadeIn(1000)
    });
});
```

```css
body{height:1000px}
img{width:150px;position:fixed;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="logo" src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Images.jpg" />
```

Comment: The image change the correct way but still no fade effect :(